# Bash Output Dropped?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, output

Here's my code. It's basically just grep'ing and making the output look nicer.
It works just fine, however if I use REGEX input the output is blank. The "myVar" which counts the # of grep lines returned seems to be correct, but it seems like awk is losing the output text.

Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
center() {
  termwidth="$(tput cols)"
  padding="$(printf '%0.1s' ={1..500})"
  printf '%*.*s %s %*.*s\n' 0 "$(((termwidth-2-${#1})/2))" "$padding" "$1" 0 "$(((termwidth-1-${#1})/2))" "$padding"
}

if [ $1 = "-h" ] || [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 'USAGE: ./Check.sh [PATTERN1] [PATTERN2] [PATTERN3] ... [PATTERN20]
Search for PATTERN in the HOSTS file. Patterns can be in the Perl REGEX form.'
else
        for item in "$@"
          do
          center "SEARCHING $item"
          grep -i $item /etc/hosts
          myVar=$(wc -l <(grep -i -P $item /etc/hosts) | awk '{print $1}')
          if [ $myVar -eq 0 ]; then
                center "COULD NOT FIND $item"
          fi
          center "FOUND $myVar IN $item"
        done
fi
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ ./Check.sh '^142.[0-9]+'
=================================================================== SEARCHING ^142.[0-9]+ ===================================================================
================================================================= FOUND 945 IN ^142.[0-9]+ ==================================================================
$ cat /etc/hosts | grep -i -P -c '^142.[0-9]+'
945
```

If I input a non-regex string the output and count are both fine. The file being grep'ed is a corporate host file so I can't share successful output, but basically the matched lines go between the "SEARCHING" and "FOUND" line.

Comment: Several quoting issues, btw -- consider fixing what http://shellcheck.net/ finds before asking questions here.

Comment: I'd also tend to suggest using `bash -x yourscript` to generate trace-level logging and thus narrowing down misbehavior early -- you can see that way how `grep` is being called, for example, and then call it yourself the same way and compare results.

Comment: That said, I don't know what you mean by "losing the output text" -- `myVar` contains the output of `awk`, so if that variable is non-empty, that text can't by definition be lost.

Comment: Do you mean you want the text to be emitted directly from the prior call? Notice that you aren't using `-P` in that call, so the prior `grep` instance isn't treating your input like a PCRE?

Comment: What I mean is if I run the script with a non-regex argument I get a ton of lines between "SEARCHING" and "FOUND". I would expect to only see them sandwiched together like above if it reads "FOUND 0". So what I mean is I don't know where all those lines went. They show up if I don't use a regex.

Comment: If you pass a regex that only matches with `-P`, then the `count` will include these matches, but the output from the prior grep without `-P` will not. Which is to say -- your code should use `-P` in both `grep` invocations or not at all; using it in one invocation but not the other makes both sense.

Comment: Wow! I just noticed that. My bad. Thanks!

Comment: That's what my answer from an hour ago, and my comment [from the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51504983/bash-output-dropped?noredirect=1#comment89979357_51504983), was trying to point out. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not that content from the first `grep` is being dropped somehow (which is impossible without terminal control characters clearing the screen or moving the cursor upwards, as that output was already sent to the terminal before `awk` is started). Rather, the second `grep` is being run with different arguments, such that *only* the `grep` whose output goes to `wc -l` and then to `awk` is parsing its argument as a PCRE-style regex at all.

---

Change:

```
grep -i $item /etc/hosts
```

To:

```
grep -i -P "$item" /etc/hosts
```